# Setting variable from json in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I currently have a query from `php` outputting `json` that is one simple value. The json looks like this `{"value":53}`. I am trying to set that value as a variable in jquery function. The json I have is this and have tried all suggestions and ways that I have found but it still does not set that as a variable.

My current code in jquery is this:

```
var test = 
$.ajax({
     url: "ajax/graphs.ajax.php",
     dataType: "json",
     data: { get_param: 'value' },
     success: function(data) {
         return data;
    }
})
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, the return wont work.

Answer (score 0):

- AJAX is asynchonous;
- "success function" scope is not the "main" scope;

Alternatives:

```
var test;
$.ajax({
     url: "ajax/graphs.ajax.php",
     dataType: "json",
     async : false,
     data: { get_param: 'value' }
}).success(function(data) {
     test = data;
});


var test = $.ajax({
     url: "ajax/graphs.ajax.php",
     dataType: "json",
     async : false,
     data: { get_param: 'value' }
});

console.log(teste.responseText)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test;
$.ajax({
 url: "ajax/graphs.ajax.php",
 dataType: "json",
 async : false,
 data: { get_param: 'value' }
}).success(function(data) {
 test = $.parseJSON(data);
});
```

now the test variable is an array.